# Is a negative slope of Williamson-Hall plot, X-ray diffraction data right?

Tags: solid-state-physics, diffraction, x-rays

I have Ag (silver) powder sample and I measured xdd of the sample and got very good $2\theta$ peak. Since I want to know bulk modulus and Young's modulus of Ag(silver), I get a Williamson-Hall plot like below

[image]

I think the slope is proportional to Young's modulus of material and the value have to be positive. However, I got negative slope value. From this graph, What kind of meaning can I get?

Also, can I know Young's and bulk modulus from this negative slope data?

Comment: That data does not look very good to me and I doubt a linear fit is the best fit to the data.

Answer (score 0):

The negative slope of Fig. indicates that microstrains cannot be a dominant source of broadening. From these results it can be inferred that the influence of domain/crystallite size and micro strains is negligble

taken from J. Appl. Cryst. (1991). 24, 913-919